# Looking for a good, video game retro (pixel-like) web safe font

Tags: fonts, web-safe

Does anyone know of a good pixel-like, retro video game font that is web-safe? I am having trouble finding one.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the "true" web-safe fonts really fit your description (W3Schools has compiled a useful list of safe options: [W3Schools page on web-safe fonts](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp)).

What you could do is use the @font-face rule, it's widely supported nowadays and pretty easy to implement: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

My favourite old school game font is Arcade Classic, you can get it here: http://www.dafont.com/arcade-classic-pizz.font

Comment: Just to point out, although it may give a useful answer in this this case, W3schools is not any kind of authority.

Comment: Yes, sorry, "approved" was probably too strong a word. What I meant is that they've compiled a useful list which covers this topic. I'll edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, no one is an "authority". Damn browsers, being all different.

Comment: Check out the @font-face-property in css for websafe fonts! All fonts are websafe thees days!

Comment: The Arcade Classic font is only free for non commercial purpose..

Comment: The OP only asked that it was web-safe.